# Interface and its accessibility

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, class-design

I have been asked a question in an interview about interfaces. I am not sure whether it's really possible. Please see the question below.

There are 3 interfaces `A`, `B`, and `C`.  `A` inherits from interfaces `B` and `C`:

```
public interface A : B,C
{

}
```

We have to make sure that users of this interfaces can't use `B` and `C` directly or independently and have to use only `A`.

I could think of the following scenarios:

1. Make `B` and `C` inner interfaces.   But I don't see any real use as I could directly define all the members in `A` itself.
2. Make `B` and `C` private interfaces. But how can I make it?  Also, I have seen at the below MSDN link that `B` and `C` have to be at least as accessible as A: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664578%28v=VS.71%29.aspx.

Is there any way to do this or is the question itself wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for would be a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

If `A` implements `B` this way, it should always be usable directly as a `B`.  Trying to prevent this would be violating one of the main precepts of object oriented design.

I suspect the interviewer was trying to see if you understood this core concept, and would say "This is wrong because ..." right from the start.

Comment: Thanks for your view on this. Is there any good book or online articles which talk about better design principles

Comment: @sveerap: Read up on SOLID: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like that's a bad design pattern from the get-go. If users are required to inherit both `B` and `C`, as you said, it make more sense to just create the one interface. Secondly, `B` and `C` must be at least as accessible as A. (You can't make them internal or private if A is public).

I think the only *real* solution is to combine the interface definitions into A, rather than having the three seperately.

Comment: I too have sort of similar opinion

Answer (score 0):

> We have to make sure that users of
>   this interfaces can't use B and C
>   directly or independently and have to
>   use only A.

You don't need to obscure B or C to force someone to use just A, wherever you are using B or C and want to wait just A, please change it to A.

hope it helps!